Как исправить: "constructed value does not match the lookup key" в absl::flat_hash_set
Я использую реализацию set от abseil. И когда я изменил функцию сравнения для Indexed<T_>:
было:
template<typename T_>
auto Indexed<T_>::operator==(Indexed<T_> const& indexed) const -> bool {
    return indexed.id_ == id_;
}


стало:
template<typename T_>
auto Indexed<T_>::operator==(Indexed<T_> const& indexed) const -> bool {
    return indexed.id_ == id_ && id_ != 0;
}


я получаю:
Interface_Engine_ex: .../abseil-src/absl/container/internal/raw_hash_set.h:3156: 
  void absl::container_internal::raw_hash_set<
    absl::container_internal::FlatHashSetPolicy<ie::Indexed<ie::TextStyle>>, 
    absl::hash_internal::Hash<ie::Indexed<ie::TextStyle>>, 
    std::equal_to<ie::Indexed<ie::TextStyle>>, 
    std::allocator<ie::Indexed<ie::TextStyle>>>::emplace_at(size_t, Args &&...) 

[Policy = absl::container_internal::FlatHashSetPolicy<ie::Indexed<ie::TextStyle>>, 
  Hash = absl::hash_internal::Hash<ie::Indexed<ie::TextStyle>>, 
  Eq = std::equal_to<ie::Indexed<ie::TextStyle>>, 
  Alloc = std::allocator<ie::Indexed<ie::TextStyle>>, 
  Args = <ie::Indexed<ie::TextStyle>>]: 

Assertion `PolicyTraits::apply(FindElement{*this}, *iterator_at(i)) == iterator_at(i) && 
  "constructed value does not match the lookup key"' failed.

При этом хеш-функция выглядит так:
template<typename T_>
auto std::hash<ie::Indexed<T_> >::operator()(ie::Indexed<T_> const& indexed) -> size_t{
    return indexed.get_id();
}


Сомневаюсь, что он требует идеальный хеш. Можете добавить [mcve]?

Я не смог создать минимально воспроизводимый пример, точнее там всё работало корректно. Так что  я не знаю в чём проблема. Предположение о том что abseil требует идеальные хеш функции я сделал из-за того что ошибка возникла когда я сделал функцию не идеальной.

Скорее всего проблема не в не-идеальности, а в том что у вас хеш зависит от адреса объекта (или вообще сломан, и при нескольких вызовах std::hash подряд для одного значения выдает разные хеши).

А, ну дык == кривой. Он (для хеш-мапы) обязан в том числе быть рефлексивным, т.е. сравнение объекта самого с собой должно давать true.

Подобное работает корректно: https://godbolt.org/z/c4qxh3xvE

Помогло изменение функции сравнения на:
template<typename T_>
auto Indexed<T_>::operator==(Indexed<T_> const& indexed) const -> bool {
    return (indexed.id_ == id_ && id_ != 0) || this == &indexed;
}

